# Android eclipse project is broken

Tags: android, eclipse, git

After switching to my release branch the project had a missing gen file so I added the gen file from java build path.

Now the assets and the res folders are show like gray packages and not folders and I get the errors like res/values/ is missing.

How to return to the standard android project structure in eclipse?

Is there a standard way of returning to the standard Android project. I have become tired to fix project properties and I have tried to clean and restart eclipse It seams that some project metadata is saved the wrong way.

Thanks .

Comment: I guess the .project file or the .classpath file is missing. Switch to the master branch, copy those files, and put them in your release branch.

Comment: the same is on every branch after I merged

Comment: the problem was the class file, so I copy it form a different project and it worked ok, thanks

Answer (score 1):

/gen/ folder is automatically generated during compilation. You should include that and /bin/ and also /.properties/ to .gitignore to avoid having to fix properties all the time and also minimise the amount of unnecessary data stored in your repo.