# Android project is broken eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

my all android projects with `Eclipse` do not work now but yesterday they were fine and i was just trying to commit my project , i did not success and close it.

Now i have problems, always red lines. It does not accept imports , for example "`import android.os.AsyncTask;`" is underlined red.

in my **activitymain.xml**,

> Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?
>   Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.
>
> NOTE: This project contains resource errors, so aapt did not succeed, which can cause rendering failures. Fix resource problems first.
>
> Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
>   Couldn't find theme resource ?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge for the current theme
>   Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
>   The following classes could not be found:
>   - TextView (Change to android.widget.TextView, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

I have searched this problem, [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762006/android-eclipse-project-is-broken)  It is similar but i can not do by copying to a new project.

I have published the project on `Google Play Store`. What is the cause of this problem, I am waiting for your helps, thanks a lot...

Comment: Try to clean your Project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to "Fix project properties" (right click on project name in `Project Explorer -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties`) and then "Clean project" (`Project -> Clean`)